# Formik - how to clear a field and show a custom error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using Formik in React to create a login form. If the user enters incorrect login details, I want to:

1. Clear the password field.
2. Reset the password field to untouched, so that this doesn't trigger the password error message.
3. Show a custom error message, telling the user their details weren't recognised.

```
const onSubmit = (values, { setTouched, setFieldValue, setFieldError, setSubmitting }) => {
  // do some login stuff
  // on login error, do the following:
  setTouched({});
  setFieldValue('password', '');
  setFieldError('general', "Oops! Sorry, we couldn't log you in.");
};
```

Each of those things (setTouched, setFieldValue, setFieldError) works individually, but if I do them all at once then my custom general error doesn't show.

I'm guessing it's some sort of async thing, causing these things to happen out of order and hide the error, but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help with what I'm trying to achieve? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I have subsequently tried using `resetForm` with no success. The same thing happens - resetting the form and then setting a field error has no effect:

```
const onSubmit = (values, { resetForm, setFieldError, setSubmitting }) => {
  login(values).catch(() => {
    // do some login stuff
    // on login error, do the following:
    resetForm();
    setFieldError('general', "Oops! Sorry, we couldn't log you in.");
    setSubmitting(false);
  });
};
```

I have, however, had some success using a timeout instead. Even a 1 millisecond timeout actually seems to do the job and solve the issue:

```
const onSubmit = (values, { setFieldTouched, setFieldValue, setFieldError, setSubmitting }) => {
  login(values).catch(() => {
    // do some login stuff
    // on login error, do the following:
    setFieldTouched('password', false);
    setFieldValue('password', '');
    setTimeout(function () {
      setFieldError('general', "Oops! Sorry, we couldn't log you in.");
    }, 1);
    setSubmitting(false);
  });
};
```

Comment: there is a `resetForm` method available on `onSubmit`, that accepts an object that you can fill up with the values you are getting within onSubmit and leave the password property as an empty string. Have a look at this github issue explaining it more https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/446

Comment: @Dax thanks, this seems to have the same issue though - I can reset the form, but when then setting my field error message afterwards, it does not show.

Comment: can you update your code with the login stuff you described in comments?

Comment: @Dax have updated with that example. Also updated with another example where simply using a 1ms timeout appears to solve the issue, although this feels a bit bodged.

Comment: Did some more research in to your issue, I'm not sure this will do anything to your problem but have you tried setting the third parameter of  `setFieldValue()` to false? Like so: `setFieldValue('password', '', false)` If this doesn't change anything it might be better to make a github issue on the formik page to get a working solution from one of the contributors